# How to calculate the distance between two vectors of 6 elements?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

I have two vectors, V1 and V2 where:

```
 V1 = [0.0084    0.1871    0.1033    0.3332    0.3156    0.0524];
 V2 = [0.0176    0.2079    0.1245    0.2954    0.2510    0.1036];
```

How do I calculate the distance geometry between the two vectors ?

Comment: What do you mean by "distance geometry"? Do you want to calculate the distance between them as vectors of $\Bbb R^6$? If so, just use the definition: $$d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x=(x_1,x_2, \cdots x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2, \cdots y_n)$ points in $\mathbb{R^n}$ The distance between the points is given by $d(x,y)=\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2+ \cdots + (y_n-x_n)^2}$
in your case
$v_1=x$ and $v_2=y$ in $\mathbb{R^6}$.

Just substitute in $d(x,y)$ you should get a square root of a sum of six squares.